# Issue Connecting PHP Mysql Jquery Bootstrap together and use them | using bootstrap modal and using my own jquery code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to code a website.  On the inbox page I have a list of messages received via PHP and MySQL and styled by CSS.  What I'm trying to do is to open a bootstrap modal when you click on each message.  Now I'm trying to use JQuery to change the MySQLi using ajax and save the fact that the message has been read, and at the same time to use a bootstrap modal to open the message and let the user read the contents.  But when I try to use JQuery and ajax to do so, it just keep doing nothing.  Here is the code of the page...

**inbox page**

```
    if ($row['readed'] == 0) {
        $action = '<a href="setasread.php?id='.$row["id"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal'.$row["id"].'" title="View" class="viewmarkajax"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> | <a href="setasread.php?id='.$row["id"].'" title="Mark as read"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>';
        $message_read_color = 'class="warning"';
    }
    else {
        $action = '<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal' . $row["id"] . '" title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' .
                  ' | ' .
                  '<a href="setasunread.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '" title="Mark as unread"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
        $message_read_color = 'class="success"';
    }

    echo '<tr ' . $message_read_color . '>\n';
    echo '    <td>' . $row["sender_name"] . '</td>\n';
    echo '    <td><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["subject"] . '</a></td>\n';
    echo '    <td>' . $row["date"] . '</td>\n';
    echo '    <td>' . $rowtype . '</td>\n';
    echo '    <td>' . $action . '</td>\n';
    echo '</tr>\n\n';

    $message_content = $row["message"];

    echo '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal' . $row["id"] . '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">\n';
    echo '    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">\n';
    echo '        <div class="modal-content">\n';
    echo '            <div class="modal-header">\n';
    echo '                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\n\n';

    echo '                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Subject: ' . $row["subject"] . '</h4>\n';
    echo '            </div>\n\n';

    echo '            <div class="modal-body">\n';
    echo '                From: ' . $row["sender_name"] . '<br>\n';
    echo '                Date Recieved: ' . $row["date"] . '<br><br>\n';
    echo '                ' . $message_content . '\n';
    echo '            </div>\n\n';

    echo '            <div class="modal-footer">\n';
    echo '                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\n';
    echo '            </div>\n';
    echo '        </div>\n';
    echo '    </div>\n';
    echo '</div>\n';
}
```

**setasread.php**

```
require 'include/functions.php';
require 'include/usercnfg.php'; 

if ( isset( $_GET['id'] ) && !empty( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
    $messageid = $_GET['id'];

    $fquery = "SELECT `readed` FROM `messages` WHERE `id`=".$messageid;

    $fquery_run = mysqli_query( $conn, $fquery );

    $userdetails = mysqli_fetch_row( $fquery_run );

    if ( $userdetails[0] == 0 ) {
        $query = "UPDATE `messages` SET `readed`=1 WHERE `id`=" . $messageid;
        $query_run = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );
        $myredirection = "index.php?action=inbox";
        header( 'Location: ' . $myredirection );
    }
    else {
        echo "Already read.";
    }
}
else {
    echo "No id specified.";
}
```

**jquery code**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.viewmarkajax').click(function() {
        $.get($(this).attr('href'), function() {});
        return false;
    });
});
```

So as you can see I am trying to use bootstrap modal and define my own JQuery as well.  But apparently I can not do so.  Can anyone tell me a way to do it?

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: yes i have included... i am using bootstrap so that is required... that code does work but when i use them one at the time. when i use them together its like using two different jquery codes at the same time which i think could be the problem.

Comment: I have edited your Question to improve the layout so as to aid in debugging.  Please note the more consistent indenting and bracket placement, and how I split the `$action` assignment into three easier to read segments rather than one much longer one.  Also, I have changed your HTML producing `echo` statements so that the generated HTML code will be better laid out and thus easier to read and debug.